# json not bring the html components

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have this code in Coldfusion

```
<cffunction name="FieldsofSelectedTable" output="false" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="tableList" required="true" type="any">
        <cfscript>
            var tablesLists = utils.arrayDistinct(arguments.tableList);
            var options = "";
            var fields = '';

            for (eachTable in tablesLists) {
                var result = getcolumns(eachTable);
                loop query="result" {
                    options &= "<option value='#result.field#'>" & #field# & "</option>";
                }
                var fields &= serializeJSON(getcolumns(eachTable,1),"struct");
                
            }
            fields = ReReplace(fields,'^\s*\[|]\s*$','','all');
            fields = Replace(fields,'][',',','all');
            var createCode =  '{"fieldOptions":' & '"' & options & '"' & "," & '"fields":' & "[" & fields & "]" &'}';
            return createcode;
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
```

when i do the dump, i get the options data, but when i am using it, it breaks

here is how my dump looks like

```
{
  "fieldOptions": "<option value='dbo.errors.id'>dbo.errors.id</option><option value='dbo.errors.code'>dbo.errors.code</option><option value='dbo.errors.errorid'>dbo.errors.errorid</option><option value='dbo.errors.template'>dbo.errors.template</option><option value='dbo.errors.error_message'>dbo.errors.error_message</option><option value='dbo.errors.line'>dbo.errors.line</option><option value='dbo.errors.error_type'>dbo.errors.error_type</option><option value='dbo.errors.datein'>dbo.errors.datein</option><option value='dbo.errors.status'>dbo.errors.status</option><option value='dbo.errors.viewed'>dbo.errors.viewed</option>",
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.id"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.code"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.errorid"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.template"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.error_message"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.line"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.error_type"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.datein"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.status"
    },
    {
      "field": "dbo.errors.viewed"
    }
  ]
}
```

but when i view in inspector preview, all options are removed from the `fieldOptions`

what i am doing wrong here, i am on Lucee

Comment: I think this is not an issue. `inspector preview` tries to render html code. But since you have only `<option>` tag, it shows the content of the tag. Did you try `console.log() ` for the response?

Comment: i did tried and in the console, it does show me the data

Comment: also, i used the following php code to convert it https://pastebin.pl/view/0fd5a27e

Comment: Don't rely on the inspector preview to check if html element is returned from ajax call. Check in the raw format.

Comment: in raw format it does not bring the options